# How can i save a json file with javascript or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I have locally stored a json file, im working with it but i cannot save it, loosing persistance. This code is in my web controller (angularjs)

```
$http.get("users.json")
            .then(function(res) {
                $scope.users = res.data;
            });

        $scope.addUser = function() {
            $scope.users.push({
                name: $scope.user
            });

            $scope.user = "";            
        }

        $scope.removeUser = function() {
            $scope.users.pop({
                name: $scope.user
            });

            $scope.user = "";            
        }
```

i know that another way is local storage, but i couldn't use it because i cant list every object in my html code (it says i cannot push or pop in a undefiened object).

So, how can i do it?

Thanxs!

Comment: can't save to file from browser. localStorage is stored as string so not clear what you were trying to do to `push` to it. You can stringify data to it however quite easily and parse back to array/object while working

Comment: JSON.stringify(dataObject) is your friend. then JSON.parse(dataAsString) to get it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks yo everybody, finally i save the data in my localstorage using de json file with parse and stringify !

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    var jsonData = [];

    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }

    jsonData.push ({
        name: $scope.user
    });

    localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    $scope.users = jsonData;
    $scope.user = "";            
}

$scope.removeUser = function(user) {

    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }

    for (var index in jsonData) {
        if (jsonData[index].name === user.name) {
            jsonData.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    $scope.users = jsonData;
    $scope.user = "";            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to initialize your users variable before calling the http request.

```
$scope.users = [];
$http.get("users.json")
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.users = res.data;
        });
```

Hope it will fix the undefined object issue.

Comment: not required...is being reassigned in callback which breaks original reference anyway

Comment: Right @charlietfl, I was trying to explain here 'undefiened object' error which he was getting, probably he tried to addUser and removeUser action prior to http request complete.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that another way is local storage, but i couldn't use it
>   because i cant list every object in my html code (it says i cannot
>   push or pop in a undefiened object).

You can use it if you store data properly by checking whether data is available or not and then adding it. Other option is if `user` data is going to use for different page's or controller then you can use [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

In below code you haven't define `$scope.users` which throws error.

```
// $scope.users = [];  // Uncomment code if variable is not defined
// $scope.user = '';  //  Uncomment code if variable is not defined
$http.get("users.json")
     .then(function(res) {
        $scope.users = res.data;  // Throws error if not defined earlier
});

$scope.addUser = function() {
  $scope.users.push({
    name: $scope.user   // Here $scope.user throws error if not defined earlier
  });

  $scope.user = "";
};
```

Comment: and if you use local storage with angular make sure you can mock it away in your tests by using a serivice like https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage